# IPAD - SAFARI: Is there a way to set autofill ON for names and passwords without doing it from the safari settings menu?

Tags: javascript, ipad, cookies, safari, tablet

I'm coding a multi-channel e-commerce web-application and I need to code the "remember me" functionality for the login component. It works well on desktop but not on ipad.

On IPAD - SAFARI Is there any way to do it by programming languages in order to force the browser to set the autofill functionality ON?